# devexpress datagrid does not pass all columns in update

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have a `CustomStore` like below:

```
this.dataSource = new CustomStore({
  key: "id",
  load: ()=>this.sendRequest("GET"),
  insert: (values) => this.sendRequest("POST",JSON.stringify(values)),
  update: (key, values) => this.sendRequest("PUT", {
    id: key,
    values: values
   }),
});
```

and alow implementation of `SendRequest` is like this :

```
  sendRequest(method: string = "GET", data: any = {}): any {

let result;
switch(method) {
    case "GET":
        result = this.mService.get();
        break;
    case "POST":
        result = this.mService.create(data);
        break;
    case "PUT":
      debugger;
      let manu: IManu = { id: data.id, name: data.values.name,description:data.values.description };
      result = this.mService.update(manufacture);
          break;
        
}

return result
    .toPromise()
    .then((data: any) => {
        return method === "GET" ? {data:data.items,totalCount: data.items.length} : data;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        throw e && e.error && e.error.Message;
    });
```

}

and html tamplate is :

```
    <div class="content-block">
  <dx-data-grid class="dx-card wide-card" [dataSource]="dataSource" [remoteOperations]="true" [showBorders]="false" [focusedRowEnabled]="true"
                [focusedRowIndex]="0" [columnAutoWidth]="true" [columnHidingEnabled]="true"
                (onSaving)="logEvent('Saving')">

    <dxo-paging [pageSize]="10"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-pager [showPageSizeSelector]="true" [showInfo]="true"></dxo-pager>
    <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>
    <dxo-selection mode="multiple"   [deferred]="true"></dxo-selection>

    <dxo-editing mode="popup" [allowUpdating]="true" [allowDeleting]="true" [allowAdding]="true" >
      <dxo-popup title="Manu" [showTitle]="true" [width]="600" [height]="450">
      </dxo-popup>
      <dxo-form>
        <dxi-item itemType="group" [colCount]="2" [colSpan]="2">
          <dxi-item dataField="name" [colSpan]="2"></dxi-item>

          <dxi-item dataField="description" [colSpan]="2" editorType="dxTextArea" ></dxi-item>
        </dxi-item>
      </dxo-form>
    </dxo-editing>

    <dxi-column dataField="name" [width]="250" caption="Name" [hidingPriority]="2" >
      <dxi-validation-rule type="required"></dxi-validation-rule>
    </dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="description" caption="Description" [hidingPriority]="1" >
      
    </dxi-column>
  </dx-data-grid>
</div>
```

The problem is that, when I want to edit a row, in the popup I change just `Description` and in `sendRequest` method,  I just get `description` in `values` and there is no `name`, and this cause a problem for me, because I should send both of them.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem. My solution (workaround?) is to use PATCH instead of PUT.

Here's the update handler:

```
  update: (key, values) => {

        let patch = "[";

        var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(values);
        props.forEach(x => {
            var property = `{ op: 'replace', path: '/${x}', value: '${values[x]}' }`;
            patch += property;
        });

        patch += "]";

        return fetch(`orders/${encodeURIComponent(key)}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            body: patch,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json'
            }}).then(handleErrors);        
    },
```

Then the body is

```
[
  {
    "op":"replace",
    "path":"/description",
    "value": "new value"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, to solve that, you can use `onEditorPreparing(e)` event and get value of current row and store in a public variable.

`e.row.data` has the current row values.

In my case i used stored public variable values inside `onSaving(e)` event override `e.changes`.

Hope anyone having this will able to solve it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
.OnRowUpdating(@<text>function(e) { e.newData = Object.assign({}, e.oldData, e.newData);}</text>)
```

This will ensure that even fields that aren't changed are passed through on the update.